# Sharing variables between methods for C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to separate my code into different methods. GetInt for int variables, GetDouble for double variables, Deg2Rad for angle, and DrawStars for the object class GDIDrawer. I was able to do this by setting all variables as global but setting each variable to its respective method as local. I am having difficulty calling each between methods.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CDrawer canvas;
        int space;
        int x;
        int y;
        int lenght;
        double angle;
        double rad;
        double rot;
        


        Console.Write("Enter the line lenght in pixels: ");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out lenght))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an ivalid number.");
            Console.Write("Enter the line lenght in pixels: ");
        }

        Console.Write("Enter the angle of increment in degrees: ");
        while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out angle))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an ivalid number");
            Console.Write("Enter the angle of increment in degrees: ");
        }


        Console.Write("Enter the spacing for the stars in pixel: ");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out space))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an ivalid number");
            Console.Write("Enter the spacing for the stars in pixel: ");
        }

       
        rad = Math.PI / 180 * angle;


        canvas = new CDrawer(700, 800);

        x = ((int)1 + lenght);
        y = ((int)1 + lenght);


        for (rot = 0; rot <= Math.PI; rot -= rad)
        {
            canvas.AddLine(new Point(x, y), lenght, rot, RandColor.GetColor(), 1);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "I am having difficulty calling each between methods"? There is only one method named `Main` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Static** classes in C#. This way you can access it anywhere without instantiation.

Create A separate Static class file like this:

```
public static class Conversion
{
    public static int GetInt32(string value)
    {
        //Do your conversion here
    }

    public static double GetDouble(string value)
    {
        //Do your conversion here
    }

    public static double Degree2Rad(string value)
    {
        //Do your conversion here
    }
}
```

Because it is Static, you can access your methods like this:

```
var intValue = Conversion.GetInt32("12");
```